# How to build Latin IME

Tags: android, android-source

I'm currently trying to make a modification to the AOSP keyboard, but I'm having trouble building it in Android Studios, as there are no gradle files. I tried running the Android.mk file inside the project in Android Studios but the make file states there is nothing to be done for Android.mk. Is it possible to build AOSP in Android Studios, if not, how do you build it?

Comment: WHere are you finding the source?  You may have the old Eclipse source.

Comment: I found it here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Generally it is difficult to build AOSP components out of tree - it can be done with some patching but depends on the specific component and your level of determination.  Be aware that the AOSP keyboard is not as full featured as the default Android one, in particular the slide your finger typing is missing from the open source version.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[this link](https://github.com/ihrupin/LatinIME-gradle-module). Someone made a separate module including only the AOSP keyboard.

Good luck